# SQL*Plus output messed up

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

when insert values into table the values are displayed unclear
 here is the create statement

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENTMANAGER(
MANAGER_ID INTEGER,
LAST_NAME VARCHAR(50),
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(50),
PHONE_NUMBER INTEGER,
SSN INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (MANAGER_ID)
);
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTMANAGER
VALUES
(120.'TOM','JERRY',2233445,109-38-2483);

SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTMANAGER;
```

The data which I have inserted is displaying in random way:

[image]

Comment: Take some time to present your question, so others can understand. What do you mean by random way? Were you expecting it in any other way given you have just one row?

Comment: Just click on the top-left corner of your DOS command window, Properties -> Layout, set screen buffer size width and height to something bigger like 500. Then you can see the output more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with your data. The problem is with a way that result is presented to you.

Your client program, you use to connect to DB, does not have enough width so header and data are wrapped.

You can change the width and/or change the font size in your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

After you create a table run the below line to fix the issue.

***set linesize 200;***

Comment: i need to set to 500 to work on mine :)
thanks